# Can Word2Vec be used for information extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, gensim, recurrent-neural-network, information-extraction

I am using Gensim to train Word2Vec. I know word similarities are deteremined by if the words can replace each other and make sense in a sentence. But can word similarities be used to extract relationships between entities?

Example:
I have a bunch of interview documents and in each interview, the interviewee always says the name of their manager. If I wanted to extract the name of the manager from these interview transcripts could I just get a list of all human name's in the document (using nlp), and the name that is the most similar to the word "manager" using Word2Vec, is most likely the manager.

Does this thought process make any sense with Word2Vec? If it doesn't, would the ML solution to this problem then be to input my word embeddings into a sequence to sequence model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, word-vector similarities & relative-arrangements can indicate relationships.

In the original Word2Vec paper, this was demonstrated by using word-vectors to solve word-analogies. The most famous example involves the analogy "'man' is to 'king' as 'woman' is to ?".

By starting with the word-vector for 'king', then subtracting the vector for 'man', and adding the vector for 'woman', you arrive at a new point in the coordinate system. And then, if you look for other words close to that new point, often the closest word will be `queen`. Essentially, the directions & distances have helped find a word that's related in a particular way – a gender-reversed equivalent.

And, in large news-based corpuses, famous names like 'Obama' or 'Bush' do wind up with vectors closer to their well-known job titles like 'president'. (There will be many contexts in such corpuses where the words appear immediately together – "President Obama today signed…" – or simply in similar roles – "The President appointed…" or "Obama appointed…", etc.)

However, I suspect that's less-likely to work with your 'manager' interview-transcripts example. Achieving meaningful word-to-word arrangements depends on lots of varied examples of the words in shared usage contexts. Strong vectors require large corpuses of millions to billions of words. So the transcripts with a single manager wouldn't likely be enough to get a good model – you'd need transcripts across many managers.

And in such a corpus each manager's name might not be strongly associated with just `manager`-like contexts. The same name(s) will be repeated when also mentioning other roles, and transcripts may not especially refer to managerial-action in helpful third-person ways that make specific name-vectors well-positioned. (That is, there won't be clean expository statements like, "John_Smith called a staff meeting", or "John_Smith cancelled the project, alongside others like "…manager John_Smith…" or "The manager cancelled the project".)

Comment: I tried it out today and got pretty accurate results actually. I had to create a new word2vec model for each individual document though. When I tried my entire corpus as the model, it would see the word "manager" across all the documents which would diminish it's relationship with "John" who was a manager because it only saw "John" mentioned near "manager" in the first document. If I created a new model for each document, this solved that issue.

Comment: I'm surprised it works! Are docs each 10s-of-thousands of words? Or have you chosen to use a very-small model (in terms of vector `size`)? Without those steps, usual-sized (100-600d) word-vectors from tiny datasets are prone to overfitting – you get vectors 'good' at internal nearby-word-predictions, by sort of 'memorizing'/'memoizing' the small-data, but not generalizable to other uses. (& if this does work, there may be other even-simpler co-occurence-based heuristics that'd also work - "What [proper-names] occur most-often closely with [set-of-managerial-terms]?" - without full w2v model.)

Comment: Yeah each doc is about 30k words, and my size is 32 which is probably why I had any success. It worked better than I was expecting but I am still looking for a more eloquent solution. All supervised ML uses classification which doesn't really work in this [proper-name] example though.

Comment: Beware that gensim's optimized Word2Vec/Doc2Vec code will silently discard word-tokens in excess of 10,000 per text example. (You can split examples into smaller texts to work-around this limitation.)